# Django best way to check the model type of a queryset

Tags: django, action, django-queryset

I have a Django action function which I would like to use on querysets based on different models.

What is the best way to check the model type my queryset is composed of? Say I want to check for a Library class that is defined in my models.py

At the moment I can get it to work using

```
for object in queryset :
    if object.__class__.__name__  == "Library"
```

But I am sure there is a better way of doing this.

I assume somehow I do something using queryset.model. 
I have tried the following, but it doesn't do what I want it to:

```
import myapp.models.Library

def my function(modeladmin,request  queryset )

    if isinstance(queryset.model , Library ) :
        # do something specific here
```

Comment: You can use `modeladmin.model` to find the model

Comment: Yes but that is the same as what queryset.model gives me.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Ok, I see, I use `is` instead of `isinstance()`:

```
if queryset.model is Library :
    # do something.
```

Comment: What exception to raise when this check fails?