# Django - call Manager with multiple inherited classes

Tags: python, django

So I have this class that helps me override the update method of a queryset:

```
class QuerySetUpdateOverriden(QuerySet, object):
    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().update(*args, **kwargs)
        if hasattr(self, 'method_from_object'):
            self.method_from_object()
            return
```

and here's my class where I use it:

```
class MyObject:
    objects = QuerySetUpdateOverriden.as_manager()
    def method_from_object(self):
        print("called")
```

the print statement is never reached.

And I get why - the objects field doesn't inherit MyObject too.

So, the question is - how can I make it inherit MyObject so method_from_object will be called?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django best way to check the model type of a queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811362/django-best-way-to-check-the-model-type-of-a-queryset)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat no. not even close.

Comment: The queryset has an attribute `model` according to the answer to that question, `self.model` (since `self` is your queryset) would give you the model in your queryset's `update` method...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat this was what I needed. You can add it as an answer. If I have access to the model, I will get whatever method I need from it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe this is a better [duplicate target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487690/get-class-name-for-empty-queryset-in-django). I won't answer a question which I voted to close as duplicate, that's against the complete point. ;)

Comment: Whatever floats your boat. :) You can mark it as a duplicate, with the new target if you want, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You test if **self** has a method called 'method_from_object', but your **QuerySetUpdateOverriden** has no method call like this. And **MyObject** does not inherit from **QuerySetUpdateOverriden**.

This code would be work i think:

```
class MyObjectManager(QuerySetUpdateOverriden.as_manager()):

    def method_from_object(self):
        print("called")


class MyObject(models.Model):
    objects = QuerySetUpdateOverriden.as_manager()
```

Comment: "And MyObject does not inherit from QuerySetUpdateOverriden." - this is what I want to do :)

Comment: And it is what i do in my answer so... ?